# How do I prove that the dot product of a point on a level set and the gradient of the level set is 0?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

The question: Let $u:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a differentiable function. Let $I=\{x \in \mathbb{R} \| u(x)=\bar{u}\}$ be a level set of the function. Prove that if $x \in I$ then $\langle x, \nabla u \rangle=0$ where $\nabla u$ is the gradient of $u$.

My thoughts: I think I understand why $\frac{\partial u}{\partial x_1}dx_1+...+\frac{\partial u}{\partial x_n}dx_n=0$, since this would just be the total differentiation of the level function using the chain rule.

However, wouldn't $\langle x, \nabla u\rangle =x_1 \cdot \frac{\partial u}{\partial x_1}+...+x_n \cdot \frac{\partial u}{\partial x_n}$? How does this expression relate to the one directly above?

Comment: This formula can't be right. Take $u(x,y)=\frac{1}{2}(x^2+y^2)$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$. You probably want $I$ to be the tangent space at $x$. (There is also an $n$ missing in your definition of $I$ now)

Comment: You need to consider a curve defined in that level set and then differentiate.